# JQuery ContextMenu simple example not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I tried to implement this demo
https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html

On a minimal ASP MVC page, but the context menu will not open on the right-click. I've trimmed unnecessary code down to a minimum

page
http://comicnet20170410070547.azurewebsites.net/Books/WesternIntelligence

Comment: Look at the errors in your browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that the problem start when you get the error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

For 2 files: jquery, bootstrap.

In you code you can see that:

```
<script src="/bundles/jquery"></script>
<script src="/bundles/bootstrap"></script>
```

Check your files:
http://comicnet20170410070547.azurewebsites.net/bundles/bootstrap
http://comicnet20170410070547.azurewebsites.net/bundles/jquery

Maybe just add the extension of each file.

Comment: thanks... The issue was i hadn't loaded jquery.contextMenu.js -- I thought it was included in JQuery for some reason :|